# RxJS: debounceTime return all values

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Is it possible to run sequence with delay, if no other events are coming, and return all values at once?

I need some kind of `debounceTime` func, but that will return all values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need an operator that buffers events until no event occurs for a certain period of time, then repeats all the buffered events. I would try this:

Set this new operator to the Observable prototype:

```
function bufferedDebounceTime(time) {
    return Observable.create(subscriber => {
        let buffer = [];
        return this.do(x => buffer.push(x))
            .debounceTime(time)
            .flatMap(() => buffer)
            .do(() => buffer = [])
            .subscribe(
                value => subscriber.next(value),
                err => subscriber.error(err),
                () => subscriber.complete()
            );
    });
}

Observable.prototype.bufferedDebounceTime = bufferedDebounceTime;
```

Then use it as an operator:

```
yourSourceObservable.bufferedDebounceTime(1000).subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT

`bufferTime` indeed acts like an interval forever so it's not recommended. As Jørgen Tvedt Commented, `debounceTime + buffer` it is what you are looking for.

However, because this is a very useful operator. I created My custom one that Makes everything much easier, I called it **`bufferDebounce`**

I made it as a OperatorFunction in Typescript to force type inference along the pipeline:

```js
type BufferDebounce = <T>(debounce: number) => OperatorFunction<T, T[]>;

const bufferDebounce: BufferDebounce = debounce => source =>
  new Observable(observer => 
    source.pipe(buffer(source.pipe(debounceTime(debounce)))).subscribe({
      next(x) {
        observer.next(x);
      },
      error(err) {
        observer.error(err);
      },
      complete() {
        observer.complete();
      },
  })
);
```

You can test it yourself in this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-buffer-debounce

PREVIOUS ANSWER

With RXJS 6+ you can do this very easily.

As ZahiC mentioned, the answer is with buffers, but specifically you can do all of that with `bufferTime` [How to use bufferTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffertime)

So wherever your `source` is (as observable), you can:

```js
    // This will capture all responses, and return it in an Array every 2 secs
    const example = source.pipe(bufferTime(2000));
```

Comment: I don't think this will be exactly the same, as bufferTime seems to emit at regular intervals, independently of the events received.  Where a debounce emits some time after the last event.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` and `debunceTime` can be used together to achieve this goal. Check out this article:

https://dev.to/datadeer/debounced-aggregated-buffered-actions-with-rxjs-6-3koa

Comment: I edited my answer with a working example of your approach with a custom operator to make it more reusable. Good Point btw.